# addClass() function is not working in Jquerymobile 1.4.0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing mobile web application using jquery mobile.Now i am using latest version 1.4.0 Alpha and jquery core is 1.8.2.

And I m creating own style sheet.

```
.NA
{
   background: gray;
   color: White;
}
```

And i am adding this class dynamically to a control using addClass('NA') and statically if i m giving that class to my control also it is not working 
.In older versions this one is working fine.But in new version only the problem is occuring.Please suggest for this bug.

Comment: I doubt there is a bug here. It's most likely those styles being overridden in your stylesheet by another rule of a higher specificity.

Comment: use jquery 1.9.1 not 1.8.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.NA
{
   background-color: gray !IMPORTANT;
   color: White !IMPORTANT;
}
```

The `!IMPORTANT` part will make sure that it overwrites any existing style and use this one.

Comment: This will probably work, but it's worth noting the use of `!important` is bad practice. You should arrange your styles so that the most specific always overrides the common styles.